# How to know if all cells deleted using MGSwipeTableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using MGSwipeTableViewCell in my table view for deleting rows by swiping on cells which shows a delete button and  pressing on it  get cell delete or removed, using this library. My problem is that when all cells are deleted the table view got disappear and my view's layout got disturbed. So I want to get notified when I delete all cells by swiping, so I can apply or update constraint to manage the view's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use following delegate method , here you can check how many rows are left after deleting a particular cell and update your constraints as per requirement.

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion
{
      NSLog(@"Delegate: button tapped, %@ position, index %d, from Expansion: %@",


    if (direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 0) {
    //delete button is tapped or full swiped
        NSIndexPath * path = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [tests removeObjectAtIndex:path.row];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        return NO; //Don't autohide to improve delete expansion animation
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Source : MGSwipeDemo Sample code

Answer (score 0):

Where you are deleting your cell after that you can notify that how many remaining cells are visible in your table view by using this property.

NSLog(@"Remaining visible cells = %lu",(unsigned long)_table.visibleCells.count);

So by using this code, when no. of cell will be zero then you can handle your requirements.

```
[_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[_table indexPathForCell:btn]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
NSLog(@"Remaining visible cells = %lu",(unsigned long)_table.visibleCells.count);
if (_table.visibleCells.count==0) {
    [[[UIAlertView new] initWithTitle:nil message:@"All record deleted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```